# Traefik 2.2 http to https redirect

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress

I'm following [the guide](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/entrypoints/) and I'm able to access my website via HTTP and HTTPs however redirect is not working for me, any ideas on what might be wrong?

```
# IngresRoute
---
kind: IngressRoute
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
metadata:
  name: whoami
  namespace: default

spec:
  entryPoints:
  web:
    address: :80
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: websecure
          scheme: https
          permanent: true

  websecure:
    address: :443

  routes:
  - match: Host(`hello.mydomain.io`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: whoami
      port: 80
  tls: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Docker compose, so might not be spot on for you. But suggestion is to add a [scheme redirect middleware](https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/redirectscheme/) to your dynamic config file.

```
http:
  middlewares:
    https_redirect:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https
        permanent: true
```

Or just add the middleware to your service if you don't have access to the Traefik configs.

I prefer the dynamic config, because then you can register it on any service as required using `https_redirect@file`.

You do need a router per entrypoint though, using this method. And register the middleware on *only* the http router.

I'm sure there are other, better ways. But if you need some apps automatically redirecting and some not this is the best solution I've found thusfar.

Comment: Does this [break the let's encrypt `http` challenge](https://community.traefik.io/t/https-redirection-without-breaking-letsencrypt-http-challenge/11215/3)?

Answer (score 0):

I have a working configuration which uses Ingress objects instead of IngressRoute , but I hope this will help some people :

Thus, here is a working configuration :

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: redirect
  namespace: some_namespace
spec:
  redirectScheme:
    scheme: https
    permanent: true
```

and

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  namespace: your_app_namespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: some_namespace-redirect@kubernetescrd
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: your_certificate
      hosts:
        - www.your_website.com
  rules:
    - host: www.your_website.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: your_service
                port:
                  number: 80
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

So the trick is to :

- define a Middleware object (in any namespace you want, but that may be in the same one as your app)
- reference it in `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares` with the syntax `<NAMESPACE>-<NAME>@kubernetescrd` (where NAMESPACE and NAME are those of the Middleware object)